# How to parse csv file ignoring commas in the text?

Tags: python-3.x, parsing, replace

Cannot use csv module

I have the following file:

```
Header: A,B,C,D
Values: '1','a,b,c,d','3','4'
```

I need to parse the contents of the file in a list where 'a,b,c,d' is one value and not four ('a','b','c','d').

How would you do it using replace() or other beginner function?

Comment: What **exactly** is your expected output?

Comment: Ignoring the hearder, the list = ['1','a,b,c,d','3','4'] and not list = ['1','a','b','c','d','3','4']

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Try something like this:

```
vals ="""Header: A,B,C,D
Values: '1','a,b,c,d','3','4'"""

#step by step:
vals2 = vals.split('Values: ')[1]
vals3 = vals2.replace("','","'xxx'")
lst = vals3.split('xxx')
for l in lst:
    print(l)
```

Output:

```
'1'
'a,b,c,d'
'3'
'4'
```